# Nativescript Js OCR with Firebase ML kit

Tags: javascript, firebase, ocr, nativescript, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to develop an OCR app with NativeScript JS and firebase ML kit (on device). I did the steps of the following page without problems:

Plugin doc: 
https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-plugin-firebase#start-up-wiring

but When I looking for javascript doc for the Text recognition part I only found typescript versions of all (I don't know how to addapt.

ML kit doc:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/ML_KIT.md

I have on my home-page.xml the following code:

```
<Page 
navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" 
xmlns:FirebaseMLKitTextRecognition="nativescript-plugin-firebase/mlkit/textrecognition">

  <FirebaseMLKitTextRecognition:MLKitTextRecognition
      class="my-class"
      width="260"
      height="380"
      processEveryNthFrame="3"
      preferFrontCamera="false"
      pause="{{ pause }}"
      scanResult="onTextRecognitionResult" />

</Page>
```

It semms that it works. I can see the camera on my device activated in this case whit this home-page.js code:

```
const HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");

function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    const page = args.object;

    //TODO

    page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
}

exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
```

I found this code on the MLkit doc:

```
import { MLKitRecognizeTextResult } from "nativescript-plugin-firebase/mlkit/textrecognition";
const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

firebase.mlkit.textrecognition.recognizeTextOnDevice({
  image: imageSource // a NativeScript Image or ImageSource, see the demo for examples
}).then((result: MLKitRecognizeTextResult) => { // just look at this type to see what else is returned
  console.log(result.text ? result.text : "");
}).catch(errorMessage => console.log("ML Kit error: " + errorMessage));
```

but that code is typescript and I have errors:

```
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.gocr on device ECPBBCF741803200.
ActivityManager: Start proc 16965:org.nativescript.gocr/u0a149 for activity org.nativescript.gocr/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
ActivityManager: ActivityManagerService,attachApplication,callingPid = 16965
ActivityManager: New app record ProcessRecord{f7395dd 16965:org.nativescript.gocr/u0a149} thread=android.os.BinderProxy@11ce5552 pid=16965
ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: from caller=android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@22b46920 (pid=16965, userId=0) to get content provider settings cpr=ContentProviderRecord{35d191e9 u0 com.android.providers.settings/.SettingsProvider}
D/ActivityThread(16965): hoder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@23a23c91,provider,holder.Provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@3ae27f6
ActivityManager: getContentProviderImpl: from caller=android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@dece411 (pid=16965, userId=0) to get content provider com.google.android.gms.phenotype cpr=ContentProviderRecord{16a60ce8 u0 com.google.android.gms/.phenotype.provider.ConfigurationProvider}
D/ActivityThread(16965): hoder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@2b62a1df,provider,holder.Provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@17cb0e2c
ActivityManager: publishContentProviders: from caller=android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@11807976 (pid=16965)
JS: firebase.init done
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.gocr/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/app-root.xml:1:1
System.err:  > Unexpected token {
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js, line: 244, column: 20
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'ScopeError', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/debug.js', line: 63, column: 24
System.err:     Frame: function:'SourceError', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/debug.js', line: 74, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 263, column: 17
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 244, column: 33
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/xml/xml.js', line: 148, column: 13
System.err:     Frame: function:'EasySAXParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/js-libs/easysax/easysax.js', line: 751, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'XmlParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/xml/xml.js', line: 195, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'XmlStringParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 250, column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'parseInternal', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 212, column: 11
System.err:     Frame: function:'loadInternal', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 117, column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'loadPage', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 53, column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 72, column: 12
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 86, column: 20
System.err:     Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 899, column: 50
System.err:     Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 751, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 20, column: 25
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:186)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1532)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5931)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:987)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/app-root.xml:1:1
System.err:  > Unexpected token {
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js, line: 244, column: 20
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'ScopeError', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/debug.js', line: 63, column: 24
System.err:     Frame: function:'SourceError', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/debug.js', line: 74, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 263, column: 17
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 244, column: 33
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/xml/xml.js', line: 148, column: 13
System.err:     Frame: function:'EasySAXParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/js-libs/easysax/easysax.js', line: 751, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'XmlParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/xml/xml.js', line: 195, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'XmlStringParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 250, column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'parseInternal', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 212, column: 11
System.err:     Frame: function:'loadInternal', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 117, column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'loadPage', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 53, column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 72, column: 12
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 86, column: 20
System.err:     Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 899, column: 50
System.err:     Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 751, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.gocr/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 20, column: 25
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1116)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:996)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:983)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:18)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6151)
System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2588)
System.err:     ... 10 more
ActivityManager: Process org.nativescript.gocr (pid 16965) has died
ActivityManager: SVC-handleAppDiedLocked: app = ProcessRecord{f7395dd 16965:org.nativescript.gocr/u0a149}, app.pid = 16965
ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 16965
```

where I can find javascript version of this? or how could I convert that code to javascript? Probably I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Firebase ML kit, but I believe it's possible to use the `firebase.mlkit.textrecognition.recognizeTextOnDevice` function from JS code. The comments says to check out the demo for usage: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/demo-ng/app/tabs/mlkit/mlkit.component.ts#L188. So long as your argument is a NativeScript Image or ImageSource object it will work in normal JS code as well.

Comment: First of all thanks. I don't understand typescript intax jet. I asume that is something like a json. So could be something like that? MLKitRecognizeTextResult = firebase.mlkit.textrecognition.recognizeTextOnDevice({ imageSourcePreviouslyDefined }); and if it's, how can I link the view camera with that imageSourcePreviouslyDefined? I'm a bit confused about the documentation for Nativescript JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is just a superset of JavaScript, if you eliminate the typings that should give you JavaScript syntax mostly.

```
firebase.mlkit.textrecognition.recognizeTextOnDevice({
  image: imageSource 
}).then((result) => { 
  console.log(result.text ? result.text : "");
}).catch(errorMessage => console.log("ML Kit error: " + errorMessage));
```

Make use of eslint plugins so your IDE can guide you with the syntaxes.

Comment: It seems to be ok, but how can be linked the camera with the scanResult="onTextRecognitionResult"? I thought that would be automaticaly and then launch. Lots of thanks for help.

Comment: I think you are confused between two options, the XML one is for live camera feed and the `scanResult` event is triggered when OCR is done via live images from your camera. You use `recognizeTextOnDevice` when you want to perform OCR on an existing image file.

Comment: Oh nice. I was confused but lots of thanks. So If I use the xml method with an event for scanResult it must to recognise the text? I try, but I have an error: ML Kit error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'android' of undefined

Comment: Nice it works it I forgot to remove one param. Lots of thanks.